# Non canonical mode

Tags: c++, c, linux, termios

What's a simple way to using backspace in non canonical mode in linux terminal  ?

It's part of code, when i set flags:

```
struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
/* get the terminal settings for stdin */
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_tio);
/* we want to keep the old setting to restore them a the end */
new_tio = old_tio;
/* disable canonical mode (buffered i/o) and local echo */
new_tio.c_lflag &=(~ICANON );/*& ~ECHOE  );*/
/* set the new settings immediately */
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&new_tio);
for(;1;) {    

    c = getchar(); 
    switch(c) {...}
 }
```

And when i press backspace i get an

> ^?

.
But i need to erase last symbol..

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. According to the `tcsetattr()` man page (emphasis mine):

> In  noncanonical  mode input is available immediately (without the user
>        having to type a line-delimiter character), and **line  editing  is  disabled**.

Besides, if your program immediately receives every character you type, how can it be 'taken away' again?

Answer (score -1):

Do this in your linux terminal and do your coding as usual it will not show ^? when u use backspace.

You can also add this in your .profile as permanent.

```
 stty erase ^?
```

Comment: when u login to the terminal itself you must do this

Comment: Why i type a command in my terminal, like cd, pwd, ls and other, and when i press an backspace - it's all good, symbol erase. When i run my program and disable canonical mode - i get an ^? .

Comment: now, i relaunch terminal, enter you command, after run my programm, but nothing happens. When i press backspace i have an ^?.
(#>blablabla<press backspace>)
I get 
(#>blablabla^?)